# issue when interacting with Trust Wallet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm developing a dApp using web3 library. In some case the user has to decide how they want to connect, either MetaMask or WalletConnect.

So, when the user decides to connect with WalletConnect there is no problem with the connection itself but I have an issue when I want to interact with Smart Contract. Suppose I want to approve to user amount for stake or check the balance.

```js
export const schooseProvider = provider => {
// debugger
console.log("schooseProvider: ", provider );
    if(provider === "MetaMask"){ 
        console.log("Selected Provider: ", window.ethereum)
        W3 = new Web3(window.ethereum) 
    }
    else if(provider === "WalletConnect"){
       const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
        infuraId: '20c6beb49cd1402db84120a858bc74af',
        bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
        supportedChainIds,
        rpc: {
            3: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/20c6beb49cd1402db84120a858bc74af'
            }
        })
        console.log("Selected Provider: ", provider)
        W3 = new Web3(provider)
    }
}

export const approve = async (account) => {
    try{
        store.dispatch(updateAproveButtonsLoader(true))
        await contract.methods.approve(stakeAddress,'10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000').send({from: account})
        .once('receipt', function(receipt){
            store.dispatch(updateApproveButtonsLoader(false))
            store.dispatch(updateApproved(true))
            checkAllowence(account)
        })
        .on('error', () => {
            store.dispatch(updateApproveButtonsLoader(false))
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        store.dispatch(updateApproveButtonsLoader(false))
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trust Wallet doesn't support testnets for now, however you can add it as custom chain